# How to get .FASTA file from UniProt, knowing the protein codes, using R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I used `getFASTAFromUniprot` function from `Rcpi` package like this:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("Rcpi")

library(Rcpi)
ids <- c("Q9H2L4", "Q9NUN7", "P05413")
fastas <- getFASTAFromUniProt(ids)
```

And I got this as result:

[image]

What did I do wrong ? Any Ideas? Thank you

Comment: it works for me

Comment: Thank you. I cant understand why it does not work for me .Could it be something to change at the console during Rcpi installation ?

Comment: maybe the network is not available.. try it now?

Comment: nothing again..

Comment: @StupidWolf it worked once a minute ago and then when I retried it, it didnt work again.. Is it because of the network?

Comment: Generally the code seems to be fine

Comment: Might be.. I am in europe, maybe the mirror is different? I am not so familiar with this

Comment: Thank you very much @StupidWolf